# plot with x-axis at y=0

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

When plotting a graph where y has negative values, is it possible to plot the x-axis line, tick marks and labels at `y=0`?

In the example below the x-axis is plotted at `y=-10`, the lower limit of the y-axis.

I could use `+ geom_abline(intercept=0, slope=0)`to draw a line at `y=0` but that's all.

```
data1<-as.data.frame(1:5)
data1[,2]<-as.data.frame(c(-8,-2,2,6,10))

colnames(data1)<-c("x","y")
ggplot(data1, aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = y, colour = "y"), size=0.61, colour="black") + 
  xlab("X axis lab") + ylab("Y axis lab") +
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
                     legend.key = element_rect(fill=NA),
                     panel.border = element_blank(), 
                     axis.line = element_line(colour="black", size=0.25),
                     axis.ticks = element_line(size=0.25),
                     panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey80", size=0.25),
                     panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "grey80", size=0.25)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits=c(0,5)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits=c(-10,10)) +
  ggtitle("Title")
```

Comment: I suggest you switch to the base graphics system. It's really difficult (i.e., needs hacking with grid functions) with ggplot2 to have an axis inside the plot.

Comment: OK thanks, having seen the complex workaround I think I'll stick to `plot`